# Use of 'it is a good thing'

Tags: phrase-usage

I have been noticing in various dictionaries that the phrase 'it's a good thing' is used when something lucky has happened, but can it also mean that whatever 'it' refers to is in a literal sense something that you perceive as just positive (and not involving luck)?

For example: 'I overslept, but it's a good thing as I needed the extra sleep'.

Thanks!

Comment: The fact that you overslept on a day when it didn't matter might be regarded as luck!

Comment: I think the difference between ‘luck’ and ‘something positive’ is less far apart than you’re assuming.

Answer (score 1):

Consider these two example sentences:

A) *I overslept, but **it's a good thing** as I needed the extra sleep.*

B) *I bought a spare charging cord for my cell phone, **it's a good thing** to have around.*

Will the charging cord bring you good fortune? Probably not. It's simply a practical thing to own.

In essence, yes. The phrase *it's a good thing* can refer to an event/situation (e.g. Example A) or to a possession (e.g. Example B).

Hope this helps!